# AngularJS ng-show only triggering once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML

```
    <div class="alert alert-danger col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" ng-show="showErrorMessage">
        <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" ng-click="closeErrorMessage()">
            ×
        </button>
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
        <strong>Error</strong> The following errors have occurred:
        <div ng-repeat="error in createResp.Errors">{{error}}</div>
    </div>
```

With the following inside my JavaScript

```
   $scope.showErrorMessage = false;

   $scope.search = function () {
        var createOrderResp = myData.create($scope.request);

        createOrderResp.$promise.then(function (r) {
            $scope.createResp = r;
            if ($scope.createResp.Errors.length > 0) {
                $scope.showErrorMessage = true;
            }
        }, function (r) {
            handleResourceError(r);
        });
    };

    $scope.closeErrorMessage = function () {
        $scope.showErrorMessage = false;
    };
```

So everything works fantastic the first time through. If the response contains errors then the div is shown. However after clicking the close button `closeErrorMessage()` and then performing it again the error alert does not show up even though the showErrorMessage flag turns to true.

Comment: If I'm right, then `data-dismiss` will remove entire `alert` block. So the `$scope.showErrorMessage` won't matter.

Comment: You are right! i didn't realize that. Can you post it as an answer so i can give you credit?

Comment: I actually cannot recreate your issue. Even with data-dismiss I can create and close the error alert. I've created this small plunker to work on your issue, you may as well include it in your question if you like http://plnkr.co/edit/qbeVQVW72IcKs0Uud88b

Comment: try `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.showErrorMessage = true`. It might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `data-dismiss`. It will remove entire `alert` block. Therefore triggering `ng-show` with variable in scope won't help, since there won't be an html part, that will need triggering.